# JS Reload page with modified query string

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a url akin to `domain.com/?a=1&b=2&...`. I'd like to refresh the page but be able to change any of the given query string values or add it in if it isn't already there.

ie. If I wanted `b=5` both `/?a=1` and `/?a=1&b=2` would become `/?a=1&b=5`

I believe I need to use the URLSearchParams class to set the query string and redirect (instead of refresh) to the new url but I'm having trouble working out how to combine all the parts to create the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a page with a url like `/?a=1&b=2` and you want to navigate to `/?a=1&b=5` using JavaScript.

```js
// grab the search query, parse it into a `URLSearchParams` set
const queryData = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search.slice(1))

// manipulate the parameters as desired
queryData.set("b", 5)

// assemble the new URL using the current URL as the base
const newUrl = new URL(window.location.href)
newUrl.search = queryData

// redirect to the new URL
window.location.href = newUrl
```

Comment: ```// assemble the new URL using the current URL as the base

const newUrl = new URL(window.location.href)

newUrl.search = queryData```

This part exactly, thanks!

Comment: An 's' is missed.